# How can I get my text appended to the placeholder programmatically

Tags: ios, uitextfield, placeholder

I want to add a variable place holder in my textField and when something is written in textField, that text should be appended to place holder without any change to place holder. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using clearsOnBeginEditing property and set it to FALSE.

textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;

If you are creating textfield by interface builder then you have to go to inspector in Interface Builder(Press command 1) and finally you have to  uncheck the Clear when editing begins option.